# how to prepare string variables in yaml for python that asign a variable by themselfs

Tags: mysql, database, python-2.7, yaml

I need to build a Python-Script in Python 2.7 that makes a Select-Query to a Specific Database. This Script has to be reusable for certain reasons, but the Query has to be Flexible.

I wanted to add the Query to a YAML-File that is loaded by the Script, but IdK how to let YAML know that a part of the Query will be fullfilled by the Script itself:

```
query : "SELECT u.username, u.email from users u 
             WHERE u.status='active' 
             AND id=" + id + " 
             AND u.username='" + username + ";'
```

While my Python-Script uses a loop with the given information:

```
for row in file:
    id = row.id
    username = row.username
    dbcur.execute(QUERY['query'])
```

how do I do this the best way possible? I have a working enviorment that uses a query inside the script, but because we need this script multiple times and have to document the usage I wanted to store the query somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Use SQL prepared statements:

```yaml
query: |
  SELECT u.username, u.email from users u 
      WHERE u.status='active' 
      AND id=%s
      AND u.username=%s;
```

This can then be used via

```py
dbcur.execute(QUERY['query'], (id, username))
```

`dbcur` must have been created via `connection.cursor(prepared=True)`. In case you're using SQLAlchemy, see [their documentation](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/tutorial/dbapi_transactions.html#tutorial-sending-parameters) which uses a slightly different format.